# Problem booting in text mode Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nvidia, text-mode

I made the big mistake of upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer with NVidia card and the interface is now broken. I have to use Unity 2D and the games I used to play with my daughter are not working anymore (slow as hell). I'm trying to upgrade to the latest nvidia drivers, but I can't seem to stop the X server.

I tried to boot into console with "text" added as argument to kernel - it doesn't do anything, I still get a graphical login screen.

I tried killing Xserver with

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

I get a

```
stop: Unknown instance:
```

If I do a *lightdm restart* first I can stop it, but I get a garbled console screen on 
which I can't read anything

I tried booting into single mode and that worked and then a *telinit 3* brought me back to the graphical login screen.

What else can I do? Did I overlook something?

I tried to search in many places, but couldn't find an answer to my question (for everybody else the 'text' option seems to work)...

Comment: Were you finding that it is not possible to upgrade the binary nvidia driver without first stopping X?  I've never run into that problem, though I've only installed .deb's...

Comment: I was using nvidia's own installer which runs in console and checks if the server is still running (and doesn't move further if it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution - I booted into single mode and then enabled networking. This allowed me to access the disks as r/w and to run the install script.

This also solved my problem with booting into console since the graphic drivers can no longer be initialized (API mismatch - kernel is 295.40 and client is 295.49 - whatever that means) :D

...all in a day's work...